# Specifying hostname for MySQL server - connection refused

Tags: mysql

I deployed a SQL server on my Mac and configured so that root@% has access to it. I also modified my /etc/hosts to have a mapping between my Mac IP (192.168.1.60) and my MySQL server (`192.168.1.60  mysql-server`). I also added a binding in my.cnf and then restarted the server:

```
bind-address = 192.168.1.60
port = 3306
```

However, when I do (from my Mac): `mysql -u root -h mysql-server`, I can't connect to the MySQL server (and also when I do a "netcat mysql-server 3306", I have this response: `nc: connectx to mysql-server port 3306 (tcp) failed: Connection refused`).

Any recommendation ?

Many thanks - C

Comment: and when you enter only the ip adress instead of the name

Comment: same: ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.1.60' (61)